# Android: Change "Done" button text on keyboard

Tags: android

I am new to Android development. Is it possible to change "Done" button's text on keyboard? If yes, how to do that?

Comment: You mean any keyboard or specific keyboard ?

Comment: No specific keyboard. General soft keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

you can  set ImeOptions for textview in xml. their are many as per 
this 
[Link for imeOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aimeOptions)

for example various imeOptions..

```
actionNone       IME_ACTION_NONE.
actionGo         IME_ACTION_GO.
actionSearch     IME_ACTION_SEARCH.
actionSend       IME_ACTION_SEND.
actionNext       IME_ACTION_NEXT.
```

Comment: Please explain further

Answer (score 2):

```
  EditText input = new EditText(context);
  input.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
  input.setImeActionLabel("My Text", EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

Alternatively you can do it in the XML

```
  android:imeActionLabel="My Text"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this:

```
   <EditText       
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:imeOptions="actionGo"           
     />
```

and call this function to use action:

```
mInstrunctionEditTxt
        .setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                    // do what action you want
                }

                return false;
            }               


        });
```